# Laravel update column after using create method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I use the Eloquent Create method and would like to change a value for a given column

I was expecting something like this to work?

```
$user = User::create($request->all());

$user->eyecolor = "blue";
$user->save();
```

Comment: That should work, is 'eyecolor' in the $fillable property of your model?

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: Yes it is in the $fillable property, and no I'm not getting an error. The column just doesn't get updated.

Comment: I've tried changing more than 1 column, like the Title/Username. The value will get updated with what is set in the request. But not overwritten with what i set with $user->column = "value";

Comment: Go into tinker using your terminal, do the exact as above and see what response you get

Comment: I got it working, you were correct. Nothing was wrong with the code. Atleast not the part I wrote here. Thanks for your help, please excuse my lack of proper route testing :(